# Java not found from mozilla add on

Tags: java, javascript, firefox-addon, classpath, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing a Firefox addon which is required to call a Java class by loading an external jar file.

I am trying to call Java from `lib/main.js` file of my add on. A very simple line like:

```
var myString = new java.lang.String("hello");
```

It is throwing an error:

> ReferenceError: java is not defined

How can I call Java from an add-on? I am able to call any java class from a standlone js file, invoked via a html file. But when I call from the js file in the add-on it cannot find Java.

Comment: Is there an extension in Firefox where JavaScript can access Java?  (Or is the OP confused about Java != JavaScript? -- That's my guess)

Comment: Yes, javascript can access java. Look at this link : http://kb.mozillazine.org/Dev_:_Extensions_:_Example_Code_:_Calling_Java_from_Javascript

Comment: You should mention that you use the Add-on SDK (I deduced it from the file name you are using). I don't think that SDK-based add-ons can access Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a Java applet, see examples and documentation here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_applet

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/

---

Or are you writing a Firefox extension?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Java_in_Firefox_Extensions

It's not clear to me whether LiveConnect is still supported in recent versions of Firefox.

Comment: I am writing a firefox extension.I was able to use LiveConnect to load external classes when i wrote a sample.js and invoked it from sample.html as a webpage. But the same code inside the firefox extension is not able to accept anything related to JAVA. Anything am I missing?